# Group array by first element

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have an Array[(Int, (Int, Int))] like this,

```
   (24, (12, 5))
   (12, (17, 3))
   (1,  (7, 25))
   (24, (4, 6))
   (1,  (13, 3))
   (12, (9, 14))
   (24, (9, 18))
```

I would like to group these arrays by the first element, it means I would like to have:

```
   (24, ((12, 5), (4, 6), (9, 18)))
   (12, ((17, 3), (9, 14)))
   (1,  ((7, 25), (13, 3)))
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you have:

```
val arr = Array((24, (12, 5)), (12, (17, 3)), (1,  (7, 25)), (24, (4, 6)), (1,  (13, 3)), (12, (9, 14)), (24, (9, 18)))
```

You can group by using group method:

```
val grouped = arr.groupBy(_._1).map {case (k,v) => k -> v.map {case (_, (b,c))=> (b,c)}}
```

or:

```
val grouped = arr.groupBy(_._1).mapValues {_.map {case (_, (b,c))=> (b,c)}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the groupBy method is not sufficient for his problem. To have the output in the desired format, he'd have to do something like `arr.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))` to strip the key from the list of values

Comment: Dear Irundaia & Nyavro, great, thank you for your help.